# Codepipeline doesn't get triggered on code change ( Occasionally )

Tags: triggers, bitbucket, devops, webhooks, aws-codepipeline

I have aws codepipeline created with source -> set to bitbucket repo.
my webhook gets triggered on code change and aws codepipeline runs.

recently , when a code change was pushed on bitbucket repo.

webhook didn't trigger an aws codepipeline.

How I solved it.
-> I clicked on the release change ( to start pipeline )
After that it automatically triggers pipeline on code change.

Problems:
-> Why did pipeline not get triggered on code change?
-> Execution history doesn't show change , How to view if it is not getting triggered automatically?
-> Does this happen frequently and How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's being triggered manually, I would suggest checking GitHub status page, there can be some degraded performance for Webhooks for example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldb6J.png)

Comment: or BitBucket in your case

Comment: I think it was a one-time issue but will definitely check for degraded performance for webhooks.